# "appsettings" or "applicationsettings" performance wise

Tags: c#, performance, appsettings, application-settings

Which one is better in terms of performance ***appsettings*** or ***applicationsettings*** ignoring the fact that ***appsettings*** is outdated.

Comment: What platform(s)? Windows, Windows Phone? Something else? C#?

Comment: sry not to mention it before.. i'm asking for C#

Comment: I would say that if you don't have written the code yet, start by NOT using something outdated. If you already have the code, then why don't you just do a quick profile using dotTrace and you can find out pretty easily. You can even try both, save both traces and compare. Nothing beats hard numbers.